# puppeteer: how to wait until an element is visible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I would like to know if I can tell puppeteer to wait until an element is displayed.

```js
const inputValidate = await page.$('input[value=validate]');
await inputValidate.click()
        
// I want to do something like that 
waitElemenentVisble('.btnNext ')

const btnNext = await page.$('.btnNext');
await btnNext.click();
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Note about modals, just in case (I know this wasn't asked, but I feel a common enough pitfall): element visibility with modals that fade in/out is tricky. An element can be visible, but not yet clickable due to modal opacity etc. You can either disable transitions for test, or just register shown/hidden hooks, write a boolean variable on window, and wait for the right value in tests around modal interactions. Saves lots of flakes.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I think you can use `page.waitForSelector(selector[, options])` function for that purpose.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {

   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", headless: false});
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.setUserAgent(options.agent);
   await page.goto("https://www.url.net", {timeout: 60000, waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
   
   page
    .waitForSelector('#myId')
    .then(() => console.log('got it'));
    browser.close();
});
```

To check the options available, please see the  [github link.](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.elementhandle.waitforselector.md)

Comment: How can I do the same for `xpath`? `page.waitForSelector` only works with `css` selector?

Comment: `waitForXPath()` ?

Comment: @turmuka, you may want to update your code to add `browser.close()` in the `then` block; as it stands, your code will likely close the browser before the `console.log`

Comment: @joy, you could just use `page.waitFor` which is very versatile

Comment: how is this a good answer? the code snippet doesn't even go a web page!

Comment: @shafeen I proposed an edit for the snippet to work, but it still hasn't been accepted yet :/ I however think the snippet is still relevant, as it demonstrates how `page.waitForSelector` can be used

Comment: If you cant to achieve the same but wait for an element to be enabled you can use `page.waitForSelector('#myId:enabled')`

Comment: @JamieJag is right about the `browser.close()`. You could also just be consistent with async/await and not use Promises.

Comment: Example code not tested and missing url

Answer (score 86):

If you want to ensure the element is actually visible, you have to use

```js
await page.waitForSelector('#myId', {visible: true})
```

Otherwise you are just looking for the element in the DOM and not checking for visibility.

Comment: In my case I needed the opposite which is `page.waitForSelector('#myId', {hidden: true})` to wait until a loader was hidden before continuing

Comment: This does not work if the element has height/width 0. Check this answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103671/528468

Answer (score 53):

> **Note, All the answers submitted until today are incorrect**

Because it answer for an element if **Exist or Located** `but NOT` **Visible or Displayed**

The right answer is to check an element size or visibility using [`page.waitFor()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) or [`page.waitForFunction()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args), see explaination below.

```
// wait until present on the DOM
// await page.waitForSelector( css_selector );
// wait until "display"-ed
await page.waitForFunction("document.querySelector('.btnNext') && document.querySelector('.btnNext').clientHeight != 0");
// or wait until "visibility" not hidden
await page.waitForFunction("document.querySelector('.btnNext') && document.querySelector('.btnNext').style.visibility != 'hidden'");

const btnNext = await page.$('.btnNext');
await btnNext.click();
```

### Explanation

The element that Exist on the DOM of page not always Visible if has CSS property `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` that why using `page.waitForSelector(selector)` is not good idea, let see the different in the snippet below.

```js
function isExist(selector) {
  let el = document.querySelector(selector);
  let exist = el.length != 0 ? 'Exist!' : 'Not Exist!';
  console.log(selector + ' is ' + exist)
}

function isVisible(selector) {
  let el = document.querySelector(selector).clientHeight;
  let visible = el != 0 ? 'Visible, ' + el : 'Not Visible, ' + el;
  console.log(selector + ' is ' + visible + 'px')
}

isExist('#idA');
isVisible('#idA');
console.log('=============================')
isExist('#idB')
isVisible('#idB')
```

```css
.bd {border: solid 2px blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bd">
  <div id="idA" style="display:none">#idA, hidden element</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="bd">
  <div id="idB">#idB, visible element</div>
</div>
```

on the snippet above the function `isExist()` is simulate

```
page.waitForSelector('#myId');
```

and we can see while running `isExist()` for both element `#idA` an `#idB` is return exist.

But when running `isVisible()` the  `#idA` is not visible or dislayed.

And here other objects to check if an element is displayed or using CSS property `display`.

```
scrollWidth
scrollHeight
offsetTop
offsetWidth
offsetHeight
offsetLeft
clientWidth
clientHeight
```

for style `visibility` check with not `hidden`.

note: I'm not good in Javascript or English, feel free to improve this answer.

Comment: Absolutely right! However there is actually an option in puppeteer for this. See my answer.

Comment: @finn, unless the next page has the exact same selectors, which does does not allow you to differentiate between the current and next page. `waitForFunction` allows you to do this.

Comment: waitFor() is gone as of version 15 according to the release notes.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`page.waitFor()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args), [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options), or [`page.waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) to wait for an element on a [page](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-page):

```
// Selectors

const css_selector = '.btnNext';
const xpath_selector = '//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " btnNext ")]';

// Wait for CSS Selector

await page.waitFor(css_selector);
await page.waitForSelector(css_selector);

// Wait for XPath Selector

await page.waitFor(xpath_selector);
await page.waitForXPath(xpath_selector);
```

> **Note:** In reference to a [frame](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-frame), you can also use [`frame.waitFor()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args), [`frame.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framewaitforselectorselector-options), or [`frame.waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framewaitforxpathxpath-options).

Comment: Isn't it redundant to await for page.waitFor?

Comment: Yes it is, and now it's also deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

Updated answer with some optimizations:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.somedomain.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.click('input[value=validate]');
    await page.waitForSelector('#myId');
    await page.click('.btnNext');
    console.log('got it');

    browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 7):

While I agree with @ewwink answer. Puppeteer's API checks for not hidden by default, so when you do:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#id', {visible: true})
```

You get not hidden and visible by CSS.
To ensure rendering you can do as @ewwink's `waitForFunction`. However to completely answer your question, here's a snippet using puppeteer's API:

```
async waitElemenentVisble(selector) {
  function waitVisible(selector) {
    function hasVisibleBoundingBox(element) {
      const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
      return !!(rect.top || rect.bottom || rect.width || rect.height)
    }
    const elements = [document.querySelectorAll(selector)].filter(hasVisibleBoundingBox)
    return elements[0]
  }
  await page.waitForFunction(waitVisible, {visible: true}, selector)
  const jsHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(waitVisible, selector)
  return jsHandle.asElement()
}
```

After writing some methods like this myself, I found [expect-puppeteer](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer/tree/master/packages/expect-puppeteer) which does this and more better (see [toMatchElement](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer/tree/master/packages/expect-puppeteer#toMatchElement)).

Answer (score 3):

```
async function waitForVisible (selector){
    //const selector = '.foo';
  return  await page.waitForFunction(
      (selector) => document.querySelector(selector) && document.querySelector(selector).clientHeight != 0",
      {},
      selector
    );
}
```

---

Above function makes it generic, so that you can use it anywhere.

---

But, if you are using pptr there is another faster and easier solution:

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args

---

```
page.waitForSelector('#myId', {visible: true})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this by scraping a fitness website. @ewwink, @0fnt, and @caram have provided the most complete answer.

Just because a DOM element is visible doesn't mean that it's content has been fully populated.

Today, I ran:

```
await page.waitForSelector("table#some-table", {visible:true})
const data = await page.$eval("table#some-table",(el)=>el.outerHTML)
console.log(data)
```

And incorrectly received the following, because the table DOM hadn't been populated fully by runtime. You can see that the outerHTML is empty.

`user@env:$ <table id="some-table"></table>`

Adding a pause of 1 second fixed this, as might be expected:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

await page.waitForSelector("table#some-table", {visible:true})
await sleep(1000)
const data = await page.$eval("table#some-table",(el)=>el.outerHTML)
console.log(data)
```

`user@env:$ <table id="some-table"><tr><td>Data</td></tr></table>`

But so did @ewwink's answer, more elegantly (no artificial timeouts):

```
await page.waitForSelector("table#some-table", {visible:true})
await page.waitForFunction("document.querySelector('table#sched-records').clientHeight != 0")
const data = await page.$eval("table#some-table",(el)=>el.outerHTML)
console.log(data)
```

`user@env:$ <table id="some-table"><tr><td>Data</td></tr></table>`