# Decorating classes from a library

Tags: javascript, class, design-patterns, factory

I am using puppeteer for a webcrawler of mine. Sometimes it needs to click gui elements that take time to show up.

It has been bugging me that for every `click()` I call I also need to call a timeout manually.
I wondered if it is possible to decorate all the click functions somehow.

As puppeteer is a library I do not instantiate any of these myself, rather they're given from functions such as `Page.$(selector)`
the `click()` is available in multiple classes and all of them will need to have it applied.

What's a good pattern to solve this?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135853/puppeteer-wait-an-element-is-visible)

Comment: Partially, I still use the timeout because there is animation that takes time to complete

Comment: It shouldn't matter if there is an animation, though.. That method should wait until a specific element is available, regardless why it needs to wait.