# How do I access elements on modal with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I can't seem to find a solution. I'm able to click the modal, but once I target the id on something on the modal I get Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement. I'm using the below to target an id after the modal loads up from another click.

```
await page.click('#myid');
```

Comment: Can you share the code before this statement (the code that opens the modal)?

Comment: The code is literally another click to click a button to load the modal. Same as posted, but different id. I can't seem to click any element on the modal once it loads.

Comment: do the modal contents happen to load asynchronously? I have a feeling that it doesn't wait for the contents to load before doing the click. As a sanity check you can try `await page.waitForTimeout(3000);` before the click.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135853/puppeteer-how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-visible, you could try `page.waitForSelector('#myid')`

Comment: Yup. Thats it! I was pretty sure that I had set a timeout previously. Well, I did the waitForSelector.

Comment: see if `await page.waitForSelector('#myid')` works. That's probably more elegant.

Comment: The waitForSelector doesn't seem to work. However, the waitForTimeout does. Feel free to answer so I can mark it as the answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `waitForTimeout` is a race condition and very unlikely to be the optimal answer. Please share a [mcve] that shows the page you're scraping. Without it, it's sort of like trying to hit a target with the lights out.

Comment: @ggorlen agreed, I wasn't suggesting waitForTimeout was the solution, just to help determine the problem.

Comment: @Jon did you prefix `page.waitForSelector('#myid')` with `await`?

Comment: Yes. I tried waiting for the selector id for the modal and several different elements and for some reason it didn't work. The waitForTimeout did though.