# how to make it wait for it to find the element before the click

Tags: reactjs, automation, puppeteer, wait, e2e

I have to click an element but it takes time to be visible , so I use waitForTimeOut , but I want to use some other type of validation or good practice.

example

```
await generateReport.clickUiOnCreateReportPage("singleCodeBtn");
await generateReport.page.type(createReportPage.selectCCodeBox, "C8044951" );
await generateReport.page.waitForTimeout(2000);
await generateReport.page.click(createReportPage.selectCCodeDropdown,);
```

I wanna use other option to wait

Comment: Does this answer your question? [puppeteer: how to wait until an element is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135853/puppeteer-how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-visible)